# How to Align Text on Y axis and in the middle of plotBand in HighCharts

Tags: highcharts, web-component, react-highcharts, highcharts-ng, angular2-highcharts

I am trying to align the Y axis labels in the center of the plotBand but on the Y axis. Here what I have tried. I have given the label to plotBand and aligned it on Y axis. I am trying to find alternate solution that dynamically align the value on Y axis instead of setting the negative values of X inside the label.

```
plotBand: {
label: {
          text: 'Y axis Value 1',
          align: 'left',
          x: -95,
          style: {
            color: '#333'
          }
        },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A plot-band always takes all axis width/height, so using the `x` and `y` properties doesn't seem to be a bad idea for positioning.

However, you can access the specific plot-band in some chart's event and position it dynamically by using `attr` method. For example:

```
  chart: {
    ...,
    events: {
      render: function() {
        const chart = this;

        chart.yAxis[0].plotLinesAndBands[0].label.attr({
          x: chart.plotLeft
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gwnxfy91/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#attr

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, but is there any other way apart from using x to align the position?

Comment: Hi @vinamra rathi, May I know why you don't like to use `x` value? The value can be calculated based on some dynamic chart values, like for example `plotLeft`. Other options are `align` and `verticalAlign`: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.plotBands.label

Comment: The reason why I am asking is because for my use case, the way chart is set up, I have to pass negative values for X to align it properly on Y axis. In order to avoid the negative values I am looking for alternative options

Comment: You want to position the label in a custom way, so using `x` attribute is necessary. A label is placed relative to a plot-band area and a more general option to control its position is using the `align` property which can be `right/left/center`.

Comment: ack, thanks, I have used x to align the labels